# Swift table view and search controller didSelectRowAt index out of range

Tags: swift, tableview, uisearchcontroller

In Swift, I'm using SearchController and TableView with search API below.

https://developers.giphy.com/docs/api/endpoint#search

api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search

When I input to SearchController field, TableView normally reloaded(autocompleted search keywords appear). But when I select row of TableView, 'Index out of range' error(in my ViewModel) occurred in some situation and I can't figure out what is cause.

Error occurred line
`func searchKeyword(indexPath: Int) -> String?` in ViewModel

This is my code.

ViewController

```swift
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let count = self.viewModel?.resultsCount() else { return 0 }
        return count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = searchTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath) as? searchTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        guard let result = self.viewModel?.selectedKeyword(at: indexPath.row) else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.configureCell(result: result.name)
        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased() else { return }
        self.viewModel?.fetchKeywords(searchKeyword: text)
        self.searchTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewControllerID") as? NextViewController else { return }
        guard let result = self.viewModel?.searchKeyword(indexPath: indexPath.row) else { return }
        nextViewController.showNextViewController(with: NextViewModel(keyword: result))
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController.show, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased() else { return }
        self.viewModel?.fetchKeywords(searchKeyword: text)
        self.searchResults.reloadData()
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```swift
func fetchKeywords(searchKeyword: String) {
    self.useCase.fetchKeywords(searchKeyword: searchKeyword, paginationCount: 5) { error, result in
        if let error = error {
            self.error = error
        }
        if let result = result {
            self.results = result.searchKeywords
        }
    }
}

func resultsCount() -> Int {
    guard let count = self.results?.count else { return 0 }
    return count
}

// Fatal error: Index out of range
func searchKeyword(indexPath: Int) -> String? {
    guard let results = results else { return nil }
    return results[indexPath].name
}

func selectedKeyword(at indexPath: Int) -> Keyword? {
    guard let results = self.results else { return nil }
    return results[indexPath]
}
```

Comment: In which line does the error occur? In this one? : return results[indexPath].name ?

Comment: You should tell us the line for the error. Anyways, I would suggest to add an escaping closure argument to `fetchKeywords` and  call it after `userCase.fetchKeywords`  completes and then on your call site reload the table in the closure. Not sure if that is causing the issue, but if you are doing an asynchronous call to get the results, then you should reload the table *after* the fetch finished.

Comment: use self.results for getting value 

func searchKeyword(indexPath: Int) -> String? {
    guard let result = self.results else { return nil }
    return result.name
}

Comment: Sorry for my lack description. `func searchKeyword(indexPath: Int) -> String?` line error occurred.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).